# How To Change UITextView Cursor Blink Color in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift

Hello people can anyone help us in how to change the cursor blink color of UITextView in Xcode using Swift language or from storyboard.

Comment: set Tintcolor of your UITextView

Comment: @NishantBhindi can the Tint affect the text color ?

Comment: not affected @malik

Comment: Unfortunately it seems to be explicitly broken on Mac Catalyst

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just change Tint Color

```
UITextView.appearance().tintColor = .black
```

Objective-C:

```
[[UITextView appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Comment: interesting. I've tried it and it's not working for me. I'll keep trying.

Comment: you have to add it   at AppDelegate.swift  before ui loaded  `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {}`

Answer (score 8):

For some reason that I don't know, I had to run a `didChange` method because `tintColor` on its own doesn't work.

BTW, I'm on Swift 5.

```
textView.tintColor = .white
textView.tintColorDidChange()
```

It works for me!

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 4, Xcode 9.1 Beta**

I tried setting the tintColor of my UITextView in the interface builder but that didn't work for me.  I don't know why, but setting the tintColor on my UITextView to one color, then resetting it to the color I really wanted worked for me...

```
myUITextView.tintColor = .anySystemColor
myUITextView.tintColor = .theColorYouReallyWant
```

Answer (score 1):

To do it in  storyboard, do this

[image]

Set the `Tint` to your desired color.

Answer (score 1):

I tried setting the tintColor of textView and textField in storyboard. 
TextField cursor changed color, but textView didn't.

It helped me next:

```
let redTintColor: UIColor = UIColor.red

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    textView.tintColor = redTintColor
}
```

or

```
let redTintColor: UIColor = UIColor.red

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    textView.tintColor = redTintColor
    textView.tintColorDidChange()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just assign the tint color twice.

```
textView.tintColor = UIColor.black
textView.tintColor = UIColor.white
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine and looks better then double assign

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.addressTextView.tintColor = UIColor.yourColor
}
```

Comment: This is not working for me. Will stick to the double assignment.

Comment: @BogdanRazvan strange, cause it seems to me that problem was in multithreading issue